# Python List operations

Tags: python, list, coding-style

This is code I have, but it looks like non-python.

```
def __contains__(self, childName):
    """Determines if item is a child of this item"""
    for c in self.children:
        if c.name == childName:
            return True
    return False
```

What is the most "python" way of doing this? Use a lambda filter function? For some reason very few examples online actually work with a list of objects where you compare properties, they always show how to do this using a list of actual strings, but that's not very realistic.

Comment: You code is quite self explanatory. Be happy with it and move to next problem :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use:

```
return any(childName == c.name for c in self.children)
```

This is short, and has the same advantage as your code, that it will stop when it finds the first match.

If you'll be doing this often, and speed is a concern, you can create a new attribute which is the set of child names, and then just use `return childName in self.childNames`, but then you have to update the methods that change children to keep childNames current.

Comment: any() is what im looking for.  but i still think python is retarded for making this a global function.

Comment: 1) I wish you could use a different word than "retarded" to express your displeasure.  2)  What should it be other than a global function?

Comment: a function of the list.   mylist.any(expr)

Comment: There's no list here: the expression in the `any()` is a generator expression.  The `any()` function can take any iterator as its argument, so there's no common base class to house a method.

Comment: ok then this goes deeper into my disagreements with some python choices. iterator should be a class that has the any method.

Comment: @asdasdasd: that sounds like a static-typing mindset, that the most important thing about an object is what it *is*.  Python's dynamic typing uses a different philosophy, that what an object *does* is most important.  As a result, there is no common base class for all iterators.

Answer (score 5):

I  would do this:

```
return childName in [c.name for c in self.children]
```

Comment: This has the disadvantage of iterating all of self.children, and creating an intermediate list.

Comment: That is exactly what I was wondering about. Your solution obviates the problem: any(childName == c.name for c in self.children)

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it with lambda:

```
from itertools import imap
return any(imap(lambda c: c.name == childName, self.children))
```

but the original solution seems clearer to me.